# Primefaces calendar - variable null with this pattern "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: jsf-2, calendar, primefaces, design-patterns, managed-bean

i want to use this pattern "MM/dd/yyyy" for my calendar to set variable but it doesn't work.
If i use the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", the variable is set. Why ?

```
<p:calendar value="#{myBean.date}" id="cal_d" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" required="true" requiredMessage="Date !" locale="fr">
```

Comment: could you provide the bean's setDate function ?

Comment: MM/dd/yyyy is the default pattern , take a look  at the showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarBasic.jsf

Comment: My setDate... :
 public void setDate(Date date) {
  this.date = date;
 }
I don't understand...